# Xamarin SDK in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, sdk, vsix

Visual Studio can have multiple **Extension SDKs** which are used to ease the development.

> Is **Xamarin SDK** belongs to one of those Extension SDKs of Visual Studio
>   IDE?

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin SDK is an open-source framework to develop mobile application. And it is bundled as a free tool within Microsoft Visual Studio's integrated development environment.

To answer your question, Yes Xamarin SDK is a part of SDKs in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio use the [NuGet Package Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio) to Install and manage packages(Like the `Xamarin SDK` and other `Extension SDKs` you mentioned in your question).

Those packages are added to your project and you can use them to develop your project.

Xamarin is installed by default if you create a Xamarin.forms project in Visual-Studio.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin is shipped as a [Visual Studio Workload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-community?view=vs-2019#mobile-development-with-net). Although this documentation page doesn't show the individual SDK packages, they are included in the component: `Component.Xamarin`.

i.e. `Xamarin.Android.Sdk` / `Xamarin.VisualStudio.Apple.Sdk` / etc

If you installed Visual Studio 2019 and watched the installer, you'd see the names of these packages as they progress!

Otherwise you can just go into Visual Studio and click on `Help -> About Visual Studio` and see all of the various packages!